# circular single linkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

I've done some exercises in Java and now I'm stuck at such a problem - my list works incorrectly. I am sure that `remove` works incorrectly and maybe you can help me (with advice or code) to implement a circular **singly** linked list in a correct way. I am not sure whether other functions work properly, but I've tried to do my best.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Node {
    private Object value;
    private Object nextValue;

    private Node next;


    public Node(int data) {
        this.value = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public Node nextItem() {
        return this.next;   
    }

    public void setNextItem(Node nextItem) {
        this.next = (Node) nextItem;
        this.next.setValue(nextItem.getValue());
    }


    public void setValue(Object arg0) {
        this.value = arg0;
    }

}

    -------------------------------------------------------------------

   import java.util.*;



public class CircularList  {
    private Object[] array;
    private int arrSize;
    private int index;
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    public CircularList() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }



    public boolean add(Node item) {

        if (item == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("the item is null!!!");
        }


        if (head == null) {
            head = item;
            head.setNextItem(head);
            arrSize++;

            return true;
        } 

        Node cur = head;
        while(cur.nextItem() != head) {
            if(cur.getValue() == item.getValue()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("the element already " +
                        "exists!");
            }
            cur = cur.nextItem();
        }

            head.setNextItem(item);
            item.setNextItem(head);
            arrSize++;

            return true;

    }


    public Node getFirst() {
        return head;
    }


    public void insertAfter(Node item, Node nextItem) {

        if ((item == null) || (nextItem == null)) {
            throw new NullPointerException("the item is nul!!!");
        } else if (this.contains(nextItem) == true) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the item already exists!");
        } 

        Node cur = head;
        while(cur.nextItem() != head) {
            if(cur.getValue() == item.getValue()) {
                nextItem.setNextItem(item.nextItem());
                item.setNextItem(nextItem);
            } else {
                cur = cur.nextItem();
            }
        }

    }


    public boolean remove(Node item) {

        if(item == head) {
            Node cur = head;
            for(int i = 0; i < arrSize-1; i++) {
                cur = cur.nextItem();
            }

            head = head.nextItem();

            for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
                cur = cur.nextItem();
            }
            arrSize--;
            return true;
        }

        Node cur = head;
        int counter = 0;
        while(cur.nextItem() != head) {
            if(cur == item) {
                item = null;
                cur = cur.nextItem();
                while(cur.nextItem() != head) {
                    cur.setNextItem(cur.nextItem().nextItem());
                }
            return true;    
            }
            cur = cur.nextItem();
        }



        return false;
    }

    public int size() {

        return arrSize;
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        if ((o == null) && (arrSize == 0)) {
            return false;
        }
        Node cur = head;
        while(cur.nextItem() != head) {
            if(cur.getValue() == o) {
                return true;
            }
            cur = cur.nextItem();
    }


        return false;
    }



}
```

Comment: @Thomas you may call it as you wish

Comment: Writing this kind of class, in particular, requires careful testing. What makes you say that `remove()` in particular, isn't working? What happens that is incorrect?

Comment: Please cut-and-paste the code directly from your IDE after confirming that it at least compiles. This code has many syntax errors.

Comment: @DNA cause the order of elements is broken after calling `remove()` method. you may try. but i don't guarantee that other methods are 100% correct. i left code, cause it may be easier to advise ti change something rather than writing code from the very start

Comment: I would suggest you to write a test suite for your List first, then you'll have a clearer idea of how to code it.

Comment: @TimoteoPonce i don't think it's a very good idea, cause it'll take much time for me to write such tests

Comment: @thomson While writing tests may take time up front, you'll be glad you did in the long run as it will greatly cut down on debugging time.

Comment: btw, contains method is not obligatory but it simplifies performance of other methods. and for this moment, it also works incorrect

Comment: i can describe algorithms, so it would be simplier to understand my way of thinking and may be find an error (in algorithm constructing) :)

Answer (score 0):

Many of these algorithms could be simpler.

Example:

```
  public boolean remove(Node item) {
     Node current = head;
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       if (current.getNext() == item) {
          current.next = current.getNext().getNext();
          size --;
          return true;
       }
       current = current.getNext()
     }
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for post. but i need single linked list. with bringing in a previous element, i'll to modify the idea of my node and methods for adding, removing, inserting items, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of issues here beyond the list.  You seem to be comparing your nodes with ==.  This code will output 'no match'.

```
Node n1 = new Node(5);
Node n2 = new Node(5);
if (n1 == n2)
  System.out.println("objects match");
else
  System.out.println("no match");
```

In add(), it looks like you can only ever have two items in the list, so

```
head.setNextItem(item);
item.setNextItem(head);
```

should be this:

```
cur.setNextItem(item);
item.setNextItem(head);
```

Comment: thanks forthe answer. the only thing, that i need to check mathcing the objects when adding or removing them from my linkedList, thus i implemented `contains()` method. but correction to `add()` is useful. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on in your code, here's some advice for some of it:

1. In your Node class: Java naming conventions: the same way that setters should be prefixed with "set," getters should be prefixed with "get:" `nextItem()` should really be `getNextItem()`.
2. Also in your Node class: as far as I know, the "next value" field of a node of a linked list is usually a reference to the next Node in the list, and should therefore be of type `Node`, not just any Object. It should work the way you have it, but using explicit typing is a lot safer. (Please correct me if using "Object" is indeed a common way to construct the next node of a linked list.)
3. In the first case of `remove()`, when removing the head: you're looping through the list to reach the last value, presumably to reset its "next value" to the new head, but you're not actually doing it. You want something like this:

   ```
   if (item == head) {
   head = head.nextItem();
   for(int i = 0; i < arrSize-1; i++){
   cur = cur.nextItem();            
   }
   }
   cur.setNextItem(head);
   ```

   I'm not sure what you hope to accomplish with the second loop.
4. In the second case of `remove()`: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the second `while` loop - reset all the links in the whole list? The whole point of a linked list is to make that unnecessary. Deleting a node in a linked list does not actually get rid of the object (so you don't have to set `item` to `null`). Rather, you simply "go around" the unwanted object and "ignore" it, effectively removing it from the list, as in:

Original list:

```
[ Value: A; Next: B ] --> [ Value: B; Next: C ] --> [ Value C; Next: D ] ...
```

After deleting node B:

```
  [ Value: A; Next: C ] --> [Value C; Next: D ] ...
```

`[ Value: B; Next: C ]` still exists in memory, but nothing is pointing to it, so it will be removed in the next garbage collection cycle.

To implelement: As you walk the list, keep a reference to the previous node that you visited. Then, once you find the item you're looking for (using correct comparison, as Thomas noted), you can simply set `prev.setNextItem(cur.nextItem());` (caveat: untested code):

```
    Node prev = head;
    Node cur;
    while ((cur = prev.nextItem()) != head) {
    if (cur.equals(item)) {
    prev.setNextItem(cur.getNextItem());
    return true;
    }
    }
```

I hope these tips help you along the correct path.

Comment: thanks. i'll consider it and give a answer when combine it with my code